# Is it possible to use SQLiteOpenHelper to create DB in cache dir?

Tags: android, caching, sqliteopenhelper

I would like to create a database in cache so it could be wiped out when user clicks `Clear cache` button.

[image: Clear cache in Chrome browser]

In `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor there is only argument to pass a name of database, not a directory (default is `dadabases`).

Is there any option to delete such DB when user wants to clear cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of creating a database in your cache directory:

```
public class CachedDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public CachedDatabase(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, new File(context.getCacheDir(), name).getAbsolutePath(), factory, version);
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // just for testing
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE example (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, foo, bar, baz, qux)");
  }

  @Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  }

}
```

All you need to do is pass the absolute path as the name parameter in the constructor.

---

Tested just to make sure it was created in /data/data/[package_name]/cache:

```
CachedDatabase cachedDatabase = new CachedDatabase(this, "TEST", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase database = cachedDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("foo", "foo");
values.put("bar", "bar");
values.put("baz", 123);
values.put("qux", true);
database.insert("example", null, values);
```

---

Checking for the database:

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as [YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME]
$ ls cache
TEST
TEST-journal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create and open a database in a specific location, but you need to use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) class (choose one of the `openOrCreateDatabase` methods): as you mentioned you can't create a database in a different path using the provided SQLiteOpenHelper.

You can also modify the code of the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper) to match your needs. Take the source code from the link, copy in a new class of your project and modify the `getDatabaseLocked` method.

You can also take inspiration from [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetHelper.java).

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to clear the data in table`db.execSQL("delete * from "+ TABLE_NAME);`

you can also delete the tables `db.delete("TABLE_NAME", null, null);`

Comment: I want to delete contents (or DB) when user clears data in settings of the application.

Comment: When user clears data in settings of the application, all the app saved data like DB, sharedpreferences etc are got cleared automatically.